# Is it possible to go back into sculpt mode after posing a model?

Tags: armature, pose-mode, sculpt-mode

I made a simple "T" pose model out of cubes which I joined using the boolean modifier. I then added a simple armature to it and was able to pose the model. However, it now looks like "sculpt mode" on the top left has disappeared from the drop-down menu (same menu that has object mode, edit mode, etc). Is it possible to go back into sculpt mode after posing an object?

My thought behind this is that I would like to sculpt a model, then pose it, and finally refine it based on the pose. For instance, if I bend an arm, the bicep should flex; or, if I turn a model's head, tendons in the neck on one side will be more prominent. So, I'd like to add these details after it has been posed. Is that a bad way to do things? If so, is there a better way?

Comment: if you cannot see "Sculpt mode" then you probably still have selected the *Armature* object. You need to select the *mesh* object in the outliner.

Comment: @Blunder that was it- thanks! Feel free to submit as an answer if you want credit :)